# using WordPress to locate WP authors on Google map version 3

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have these codes that use longitude and latitude to locate posts on Google map:
going in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var pinkmarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/mapdemo/pink_Marker.png', new google.maps.Size(20, 34) );
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/wp-content/themes/mapdemo/shadow.png', new google.maps.Size(37, 34) );

    function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
        zoom: 6, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.5407246, -77.4360481), 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i].geometry.location,
            icon: pinkmarker,
            shadow: shadow,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i].info);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
    }

     }
     </script>
```

in the body

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<!-- WordPress has found matching posts -->
<div style="display: none;">
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true) !== '' ) : ?>
  <div id="item<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a></p>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php $i++;   ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                var locations = [
                    <?php  $i = 1; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true) !== '' ) : ?>
                            {
                                latlng : new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'latlng', true); ?>, 
                                info : document.getElementById('item<?php echo $i; ?>')
                        },
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                ];
            </script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>
<?php else : ?>
<!-- No matching posts, show an error -->
<h1>Error 404 &mdash; Page not found.</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have some difficulty switching from longitude and latitude to address. I will appreciate any help in the right direction.

I have been using the following code lately thanks to http://www.billerickson.net

```
if(is_single()):
global $post;
    $address = get_post_meta($post->ID,'address',true);
     if (!$address) $address = '123 Main St, Austin, TX';
    $google_api_key = get_option('maps_key');
    if($address): ?>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=<?php echo $google_api_key; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showAddress(address) {
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
                var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                geocoder.getLatLng(
                    address,
                    function(point) {
                        if (!point) {
                            alert(address + " not found");
                        } else {
                            map.setCenter(point, 13);
                            var marker = new GMarker(point);
                            map.addOverlay(marker);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        showAddress("<?php echo $address; ?>");
    </script>
<?php endif;
```

endif;

to get the author address on corresponding author page. What I need is using an array to put all authors on the same map, but I am still having difficulty getting the map works.

Comment: I'm trying to help, but your question keeps changing. What exactly is the current problem you are having? What are you trying to achieve with the new billerickson.com addition to your question that you cannot get to work?

Answer (score 0):

The process of using a lat-lng as input and retrieving an address is called reverse geocoding (normal geocoding takes an address as input and returns a lat-lng). Google offers some options for geocoding:

- The [**Geocoding Service** section of the Google Maps Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) provides an overview of the JavaScript client centered service, which is intended to be used in JavaScript code that will be responding to dynamic user interaction on your web page.
- The Google [Geocoding API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) provides an introduction to the API web service, which is intended to be used more on the server side for addresses that are known in advance and is not meant to support dynamic map interactions.

I've included both, because it looks like you are working with static data. But I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, so the Geocoding Service may be a better fit or something that will be useful in the future. Keep in mind that the Terms of Service for both options **require that you use the data retrieved in the context of a Google Map** and the data is not to be saved to build a catalog of geocoded data. There are also usage limits and other restrictions, so you will want to read those sections carefully. I hope this is what you were looking for and this helps -

Comment: What I am looking to do here is to use author_meta_tag such as addresses I have added to the users files in the admin area and pinpoint their locations on a map.

Comment: Since you already have the addresses, you may want to just run the addresses through the Geocoding API. You can send a request with the address, get back a lat-lng, and then use the lat-lng to place a marker on the map. Also, I notice from your JavaScript code you are using Google Maps v2. That version has been deprecated, so you should consider moving up to v3.

Comment: Yes, but I am having difficulty materializing that. I know I should use address as a variable and loop trough each subscriber address to pinpoint their location on the map, but can't get it working. Could you point me to a sample code?